# How do I watch elements of an AngularDart collection?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a model:

```dart
class WordList {
  List<Word> words = [];
}
```

It's created via dependency injection into one of my views.

```dart
@NgController(
    selector: '[list-ctrl]',
    publishAs: 'ctrl'
)
class ListCtrl {
  WordList wordList;
  Scope scope;

  ListCtrl(this.router, this.wordList, this.scope) {
    scope.$watchCollection("", onChange );
  }
```

I'd like to run some logic whenever an item is modified from that list.  How do I accomplish this?

I believe the key is in the $watchCollection, but I can't figure out what to pass as a watch expression.  "ctrl.wordList.words" will tell me when items are added/removed, but not changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$watchCollection` as you point out can only watch for changes in the `List` not for changes in the items of the list. The reason for this is that watching each object would have explosive number of properties.

```dart
scope.$watch(() => wordList, onChange);
```

You could implement the `onChange` method in a way that it would create further watches on each new item as well as deregister the watch on item removal form the collection.

Comment: I have similar question but this answer seems not up-to-date. `$watch` is just `watch` now. Also, `() => wordList` is no longer a valid expression. Can you update this answer to reflect recent changes to Angular Dart? I need to deep watch a map and I hope this should help. Thank you.